# Read from txt to dataframe with pattern in Python

Tags: python, file, split, save, txt

I have a txt file with repeating lines:

```
1.json
string 'x;y;z', hash 1234
2.json
string 'xx;yy;zz', hash 5678
3.json
```

and I really want to save it into dataframe with columns:

```
| json | string | hash |
```

As a result I would like a dataframe containing  for example in the first row:

```
| 1.json |  'x;y;z' | 1234
```

Comment: What is your question about this? What was the problem with your attempts to do it?

Comment: Looks like you need to write a small parser

Comment: I am iterating over lines in the file and I wanted to prepare three lists (json, string, hash and then prepare a data frame with them) but I have a problem with writing a condition for parsing the line with string 'x;y;z', hash 1234.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dataframe with the column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["json", "string", "hash"])
```

Then you can add the needed values to the three columns for example in this way:

```
list = """1.json
string 'x;y;z', hash 1234
2.json
string 'xx;yy;zz', hash 5678""".split("\n")
df["json"] = list[0::2]
df["string"] = [x.split(",")[0].replace(" string ","") for x in 
list[1::2]]
df["hash"] = [x.split(",")[1].replace(" hash ","") for x in list[1::2]]
```